# How to properly use srand in C

Tags: c, random-seed

The goal is to create a function that return the first n integers form `rand()` with each iteration of the loop having a different `rand()` result

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 1000

// takes length and pointer to the integer
void randomNum(int l, int * num )
{
    char str[MAX];
    srand(time(0));
    sprintf(str , "%d", rand());
    char new[l];
    for(int i = 0; i< l; i++)
    {
        new[i] = str[i];
    }
    new[l] = '\0';

    printf("Size : %ld\n", strlen(str));
    printf("Original number : %s\n",str);
    printf("Final result : %s\n",new);
}


int main()
{
    int num;
    for (int j =0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        randomNum(1 , &num);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

when compiling this code and running it it generates the same result 10 times, why does this happen when the function `randomNum` has `srand` in it that is supposed to make `rand` generate a different value each time

Comment: Read the documentation of `rand` carefully, especially regarding `srand`.

Comment: Unrelated?? (you can never dismiss **Undefined Behaviour** as unrelated) `char new[l]; /*...*/ new[l] = '\0';` <== **Buffer Overflow!** you may want to use `char new[l + 1];` instead.

Comment: Put `srand(time(0));` first in `main` and never call it again. If you seed the random number generator with the same value every time before calling `rand` you _will_ get the same result every time you call `rand`.

Comment: @pmg did notice that mistake but this is not related to why i keep on getting same number

Comment: @TedLyngmo can you explain why having `srand` in that function does output the same number when `time(0)` keeps on changing

Comment: @manuel It doesn't. If `time(0)` is different every time, the following call to `rand()` will also be different every time.

Comment: @TedLyngmo if i understand correctly `time(0)` is always constant no matter where i call it in the program

Comment: @manuel No, it'll usually return the current time in whole seconds since the epoch. That is, seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00. Your loop with very likely be done within one second and `time(0)` will return the same number. You may get lucky and `time(0)` may return 2 different values in such a fast loop and then you'll see two different values from `rand()`

Comment: @TedLyngmo makes sense don't know why i haven't thought of that